# C++: What is the difference between identifier, keyword, name and entity?

Tags: c++, conventions

In the following, is "identifier" a name of a variable `i`? Is `int` a "keyword"?

```
int main()
{
     int i;
}
```

I'm not being able to understand the difference between a keyword, identifier, name, entity.

Comment: I tried to improve your question, by editing the title and the text.

Answer (score 5):

For the variable `int i`, `int` is the type and `i` the name. For the variable itself, `i` would be the identifier; however, `int` is the identifier for the type.

Types may be, but are not always, keywords. Identifiers refer to a certain object, type, etc. Names refer to an instance of an object. Entities refer to any sort of object, including basic types (int, char, etc).

Comment: More generally, keywords are identifiers that you can't use - they're given permanent syntactic meaning that cannot be changed (perhaps with macros, but let's not do that please). The identifier `i` could mean something else in a different scope. The keyword `int` always refers to the same fundamental integer type.

Comment: Names can refer to not just an instance of an object, but to type, function or any other kind of item as well.

Answer (score 1):

`i` is an identifier here. `int` is a `type`, actually a data type.

**Identifiers:**
Definition from MSDN:

An identifier is a sequence of characters used to denote one of the following:

- Object or variable name
- Class, structure, or union name
- Enumerated type name
- Member of a class, structure, union, or enumeration
- Function or class-member function
- typedef name
- Label name
- Macro name
- Macro parameter

---

**Keywords:**

C++ reserves a set of 63 words for it’s own use. These words are called **keywords**, and each of these keywords has a special meaning with in the C++ language.

Check out the list of keywords **[here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/22-keywords-and-naming-identifiers/)**.

---

Good Read:
**[What are identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/565w213d.aspx)?**
**[What are keywords?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e6a4at9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial link.